# How to specify attachment Name in ExternalReportWSSService: deliveryService webservice

Tags: obiee

OIBEE has ExternalReportWSSService webserive with method deliveryService to send pdf contents as an attachment. Only problem with this attachment always came with a default name as "ReportData"

I setup SOAP request to send a pdf to my email as below:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:pub="http://xmlns.oracle.com/oxp/service/PublicReportService">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <pub:deliveryService>
         <pub:deliveryRequest>
            <pub:contentType>application/pdf</pub:contentType>
            <pub:documentData>abadadfasdfaf</pub:documentData>
             <pub:emailOption>
               <pub:emailBCC></pub:emailBCC>
               <pub:emailBody>V1RG</pub:emailBody>
               <pub:emailCC></pub:emailCC>
               <pub:emailFrom>test@gmail.com</pub:emailFrom>
               <pub:emailReplyTo>test@gmail.com</pub:emailReplyTo>
               <pub:emailServerName>DefaultEmail</pub:emailServerName>
               <pub:emailSubject>test</pub:emailSubject>
               <pub:emailTo><EMAIL ID></pub:emailTo>
            </pub:emailOption>
         </pub:deliveryRequest>
      </pub:deliveryService>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But not sure where to specify the attachment file name.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a defect in the WSDL. It worked when we put the pub:emailTo tag outside the pub:emailOption. Oracle acknowledged the defect and we proceeded by modifying the WSDL and using it in our integration. In the later releases this issue is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Pardon me asking but are you sure that's an "OBIEE service"? The few existing references all point to Fusion - so Fusion BI Publisher and not OBIEE the analytical platform.

Comment: Yes that was BIP.